# video player in javafx with speed control (constant pitch)

Tags: java, performance, video, javafx, media-player

I am working with video player in javafx. In that video player I want controller like play,pause,stop and speed control.

I have added a scroll bar to adjust speed of video

I want that when adjusting the speed, the pitch of the video must not change.But when i adjust the speed of video its pitch get change.

what will I do to keep constant pitch of video while adjusting the speed?
Can anyone help ?

Here is my code for seed control in video player :

```
// Add spped slider
        speedSlider = new Slider();
        HBox.setHgrow(speedSlider, Priority.ALWAYS);
        speedSlider.setMinWidth(10);
        //speedSlider.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        speedSlider.setMaxWidth(100);
        speedSlider.setPrefWidth(70);
        speedSlider.setValue(50);
        speedSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() 
        {
            public void invalidated(Observable ov) {
                if (speedSlider.isValueChanging() || speedSlider.isPressed()) {
                    double rate = speedSlider.getValue()/10;
                    if(rate<1)
                        rate = 0.5;
                    else if(rate < 2)
                        rate = 0.6;
                    else if(rate < 3)
                        rate = 0.7;
                    else if(rate < 4)
                        rate = 0.8;
                    else if(rate < 5)
                        rate = 0.9;
                    else if(rate < 6)
                        rate = 1;
                    else if(rate < 7)
                        rate = 1.1;
                    else if(rate < 8)
                        rate = 1.2;
                    else if(rate < 9)
                        rate = 1.3;
                    else
                        rate = 1.4;
                    mp.setRate(rate);
                 }
            }
        });
        mediaBarControl.getChildren().add(speedSlider);
```

Comment: @jewelsea can you please help me to get solution for my question?

Comment: no sorry, I don't know a solution.

Answer (score -1):

I think the speed of play naturally affects the pitch of the audio output. However if you must, I think you may want to drop the pitch in each analyzed sample (depending on your handling) after adjusting the speed, each time it is adjusted.

Comment: can you give me any reference how to do that?

Comment: This answer doesn't make sense, there doesn't seem to be any way to alter the pitch so how would you compensate...